# Confusion regarding the naming/selection of request parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

i am having difficulties trying to understand how request parameters are named (e.g req.params.id, req.body.authorid etc) and how they are related to other variables.

Can they be assigned any random name? (e.g req.params.x, req.body.y)

For the code below in `author_delete_get` function, it seems like only `req.params.id` is accepted. Changing it to e.g `req.params.x` will cause error.

As for the `author_delete_post` function, changing `req.body.authorid` to e.g `req.body.authorids` doesn't seem to affect the functionality.

authorController.js

```
// Display Author delete form on GET
exports.author_delete_get = function(req, res, next) {
  async.parallel({
      author: function(callback) {
          Author.findById(req.params.id).exec(callback);
      },
      authors_books: function(callback) {
        Book.find({ 'author': req.params.id }).exec(callback);
      },
  }, function(err, results) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      //Successful, so render
      res.render('author_delete', { title: 'Delete Author', author: results.author, author_books: results.authors_books } );
  });
};

// Handle Author delete on POST
exports.author_delete_post = function(req, res, next) {
  req.checkBody('authorid', 'Author id must exist').notEmpty();
  async.parallel({
      author: function(callback) {
          Author.findById(req.body.authorid).exec(callback);
      },
      authors_books: function(callback) {
        Book.find({ 'authors': req.body.authorid },'title summary').exec(callback);
      },
  }, function(err, results) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      //Success
      if (results.authors_books>0) {
          //Author has books. Render in same way as for GET route.
          res.render('author_delete', { title: 'Delete Author', author: results.author, author_books: results.authors_books } );
          return;
      }
      else {
        //Author has no books. Delete object and redirect to the list of authors.
          Author.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.authorid, function deleteAuthor(err) {
              if (err) { return next(err); }
              //Success - got to author list
              res.redirect('/catalog/authors');
          });
      }
  });
};
```

catalog.js

```
/* GET request to delete Author. */
router.get('/author/:id/delete', author_controller.author_delete_get);

// POST request to delete Author
router.post('/author/:id/delete', author_controller.author_delete_post);
```

author_detail.pug

```
extends layout

block content

  h1 Author: #{author.name}
  p #{author.date_of_birth_formatted} - #{author.date_of_death_formatted}

  div(style='margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px')

    h4 Books

    dl
    each book in author_books
      dt
        a(href=book.url) #{book.title}
      dd #{book.summary}
      br
    else
      p This author has no books.
    br
    p
      a(href=author.url+'/delete') Delete author
```

author_delete.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 #{title}: #{author.name}
  p= author.lifespan

  if author_books.length

    p #[strong Delete the following books before attempting to delete this author.]

    div(style='margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px')

      h4 Books

      dl
      each book in author_books
        dt
          a(href=book.url) #{book.title}
        dd #{book.summary}

  else
    p Do you really want to delete this Author?

    form(method='POST' action='')
      div.form-group
        input#authorid.form-control(name='authorid', required='true', value=author._id )

      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `req.params.id`, the `.id` part comes from the `:id` part of this:

```
router.get('/author/:id/delete', author_controller.author_delete_get);
```

Which is parsed from the URL that matches this request.

---

In `req.body.authorid`, the `.authorid` part comes from the submitted form data with the POST request and it likely comes from this part of your form:

```
input#authorid.form-control(name='authorid', required='true', value=author._id )
```

Changing it will affect things if you are trying to use this form field.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00 for the clarification! 

for the POST request, is it actually with reference to `input#authorid` or `name='authorid'`? 
because when i changed the `req.body.authorid` to `req.body.authorids`, the delete function still works correctly, which is puzzling to me

Comment: @JianHaoTan - Assuming you're using the body-parser module and the form is being submitted in the URL encoded format by the browser, I believe the browser uses the `name=xxx` attribute of your form controls to establish the `xxx=yyy` pair in the encoded body which will be parsed into `req.body.xxx=yyy`.